# DataBinding is not working Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-viewbinding, android-binding-adapter

Am using Android Studio 4.1 and Gradle gradle-6.5-all with this am not able to use DataBinding.

SDK Versions

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Below is my XML, BindingAdapter and build.gradle code.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
}

android {
    ....
    buildFeatures {
         viewBinding true
         dataBinding true
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/stepText"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:stepBackground="@{1}"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="20dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

```
@BindingAdapter("stepBackground")
fun stepBackground(view: View, type: Int?) {
    Timber.e("stepBackground ${view.background}")
    type?.let {
        when(it) {
            1 -> view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_shape_circle)
            2 -> view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_shape_circle)
            else -> view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_shape_circle)
        }
    }
}
```

In above code am trying to apply dynamic background based on Step Count.. But here it's not applying the Background. I have also put breakpoint to inspect whether BindingAdapter method is calling or not. But Debugger is not going to BindingAdapter method.

May I know what is missing here?

Comment: try calling `stepBackground="@{1}"` instead of `app:stepBackground="@{1}"`

Comment: Did you verify that `setBackgroundResource` is the correct method to call in your case? Other options would be `setBackground` `setBackgroundDrawable` ..

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in app-level build Gradle and then clean project->Rebuild Project.
It works for me

```
 dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```